# How to proxy Geoserver through Apache in Windows

Tags: geoserver, apache, proxy

i am using apache web server on localhost:80 and geoserver served from jetty servlet on localhost:8888. i want to setup a proxy to redirect the requests such that requests to **localhost/geoserver** are routed to **localhost:8888/geoserver**

i am following tutorial from http://gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html and i am stuck in the part where it says

```
copy the text below and right click to paste the ProxyPass into your httpd.conf file 
right above the </VirtualHost> tag.

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
```

i cannot find where to insert above text in httpd.conf file. the virtual hosts directive in httpd.conf file points to httpd-vhosts.conf file which looks like below

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost"
##ServerName dummy-host.localhost
##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>
```

i have tried and changed this httpd-vhosts.conf file with above codes, but every time i do this i am unable to restart apache server.

this is the httpd.conf file as in c:\xampp\apache\conf\

```
#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
# at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
# httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 0.0.0.0:80
#Listen [::]:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
    #
# Example:  
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
#LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file. 
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify it explicitly to   prevent problems during startup.
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:80

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
               default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
               home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

#ScriptLog "logs/cgi.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
#
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

<IfModule logio_module>
  # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>

#
# The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
# If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
# container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
# define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
# logged therein and *not* in this file.
#
#CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

#
# If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
# (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
#
CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
#
# Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
# exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
# will make a new request for the document at its new location.
# Example:
# Redirect permanent /foo http://localhost/bar

#
# Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
# access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
# Example:
# Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
#
# If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
# require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
# need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
# the filesystem path.

#
# ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
# ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
# documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
# run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
# client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
# directives as to Alias.
#
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
#
# ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
# socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
#
#Scriptsock "logs/cgi.sock"
</IfModule>

#
# "C:/xampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig "conf/mime.types"

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://localhost/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it,  
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# XAMPP specific settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

# Perl settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-perl.conf"

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include "conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf"

# Multi-language error messages
Include "conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf"

# Fancy directory listings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf"

# Language settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf"

# User home directories
Include "conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf"

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
Include "conf/extra/httpd-info.conf"

# Virtual hosts 
Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
# Attention! WEB_DAV is a security risk without a new userspecific configuration for a      secure authentifcation 
# Include "conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf"

# Implements a proxy/gateway for Apache.
Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"

# Various default settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"  
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl.scache(512000)"
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
</IfModule>

# AJP13 Proxy
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What OS and what version of Apache are you using? Was able to proxy Geoserver but I edited the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default instead.

Comment: @R.K. i am using XAMPP 1.7.7

Comment: Updated my answer. Just tested it and it works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to configure proxypass and proxypassreverse.

You will need a proxy.cgi file written in python, and python installed on your server. you can get the proxy file with the openlayers distribution in the example folder. you will have to configure the path to python interpreter in the 1st line, and add your host to list of allowed hosts.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Ubuntu, you'll first have to configure Apache

```
$sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf
$sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.load
$sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy_http.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy_http.load
```

Then append the following to your **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default**

```
 ProxyRequests Off 
 # Remember to turn the next line off if you are proxying to a NameVirtualHost 
 ProxyPreserveHost On 

 <Proxy *> 
     Order deny,allow 
     Allow from all 
 </Proxy> 

 ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8888/geoserver 
 ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8888/geoserver 

 </VirtualHost>
```

---

It's a bit tricky in Windows, you'll have to load some modules to enable the proxy. In your httpd.conf, add the following:

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module     modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule  headers_module       modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule  deflate_module       modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule  xml2enc_module       modules/mod_xml2enc.so
LoadModule  proxy_html_module    modules/mod_proxy_html.so
```

At the end of your httpd.conf add the following lines

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
   ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
   ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: http://scripting.com/stories/2008/11/19/checklistForReverseProxies.html

Comment: could you instruct me for windows? i am using xampp 1.7.7 and cannot find the files you have stated

Comment: Can you post your current httpd.conf? Just post it in Pastebin or something.

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: Please try to follow my updated answer.

Comment: yes, i have followed your answer. thank you, but i am having trouble using this libxml2.dll. i have downloaded it from zlatkovic as stated in your link and got a zip file. what to do with it? the site also mentioned that we need some other files too. do we really need them?

Comment: The link was just my source, the one I used to formulate my answer. The solution to your problem should be in my answer. Load the required modules and add the ProxyRequests lines in your httpd.conf. You don't have to download libxml2.dll I think. It should be in your C:/xamppp/apache/bin/.

Comment: it is not in C:/xampp/apache/bin and not anywhere in apache directory, should i put it there?

Comment: Yes. It would be easier that way. Did you edit the httpd.conf already?

Comment: Are all the modules for Windows necessary? I believe proxy_module + proxy_http_module should be sufficient for this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module     modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule  headers_module       modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule  deflate_module       modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule  xml2enc_module       modules/mod_xml2enc.so
LoadModule  proxy_html_module    modules/mod_proxy_html.so
 --add above line

<VirtualHost  *:80>
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).