# Setting up GeoServer - can't reach server from remote (timeout)

Tags: geoserver

My target is to set up a WMS that can be displayed with OpenLayers.

Therefore I have set up GeoServer (2.10.1) on a Windows machine (Windows Server 2008 R2) and am successful to the point that I can reach the GeoServer interface on localhost:myport/geoserver including layer previews. On the machine itself I can also reach GeoServer via mydomain.com:myport/geoserver.

But I cannot reach it either from any other computer or via QGIS GeoServer Explorer plugin...

When I copy the layer preview URL to a browser on another machine, it ends up with a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

I have tried setting the proxy URL in "Global Settings" to http://www.mydomain.com, but that didn't make a difference.

There is already a xampp installation running with Apache, Tomcat & MySQL. As Tomcat is already using port 8080, I am using another port for GeoServer.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: open the firewall for the port you are using?

Comment: Can you proxy your GeoServer WMS service through your existing Apache-HTTP service?

Comment: @nmtoken: Thanks for the hint! I did it according to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31750/how-to-proxy-geoserver-through-apache-in-windows . And it worked, yeah! Now, I still need to enable this for SSL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so for other newbies to this topic:

First, I set up a proxy in my Apache (conf/httpd.conf) by enabling some modules and adding a VirtualHost section, according to [How to proxy Geoserver through Apache in Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31750/how-to-proxy-geoserver-through-apache-in-windows).

Then, to enable SSL, I added another VirtualHost in conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf, according to http://documents.software.dell.com/desktop-workspace/4.0/advanced-setup-guide/deploying-a-reverse-proxy-server-with-apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "path/to/my/root"
    ErrorLog "logs/error-ssl.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access-ssl.log" common
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost Off

    <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Location>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "path/to/my/file"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "path/to/my/file"
    ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:myport/geoserver
    ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:myport/geoserver
    SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When I added SSL in a similar environment I used conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf rather than httpd-vhosts.conf. I am using the same domain name for http and https and it is working well.

Comment: **@RalphDell**: I figured I could have used httpd-ssl.conf as well, but wanted to stick to that guide. Did you use the same kind of virtualhost definition or does it work any different there?

Comment: Here is my Virtual host definition, it is very similar. I am not running my geoserver request through ssl.    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
 DocumentRoot "path/to/my/root"
 ServerName mydomain.com:443
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "path/to/cert.pem"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "path/to//key.pem"
 # I also needed this, on some browsers I was getting an invalid certificate error,
 # my certificate files are from godaddy and supplied to me by our IT dept ( very helpful )
 SSLCACertificateFile "path/to/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"
</VirtualHost>

Comment: I apologize for my bad code editing

Comment: with my new ssl certificates supplied to me today, by our IT dept,  I no longer needed    SSLCACertificateFile "path/to/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"